# Creating linestring layer in epsg:3857 from geojson data in 4326

Tags: openlayers

In OL3, I am confused about creating linestring layer in epsg:3857 from geojson data in 4326.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

there is ol.proj.transform function that allows you to switch between projections, in your case from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 :

```
ol.proj.transform(yourData, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

Check [Here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transform) for more informations about this function